# Failed to bind EAGLDrawable iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

Hello I'm using swift and MapBox for my project and I keep getting this error in the console every time a window that uses map box appears:

```
Failed to bind EAGLDrawable: <CAEAGLLayer: 0x17e4de80> to GL_RENDERBUFFER 1
```

I've already checked and the mapView is correctly implemented, if you need some extra code to help me I'll be glad to post an update, thank you.

Comment: This needs more information or a question.  Please edit.  Also look at some resources on the Mapbox issues list — https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/1572.  SO — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039275/failed-to-bind-eagldrawable-in-cadisplaylink-render-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem as I was. I declared the mapView as a global variable because of my code.

```
class MapaConResutaldos: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

//MARK: - mapa
lazy var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

lazy var km = 1.0
var mapView = MGLMapView()

}
```

Something like this and the problem was that the map view was being called before it got customized. The way the console error stopped showing was pretty neat and simple, just changing the declaration of the mapView to "private lazy".

```
private lazy var mapView = MGLMapView()
```

This way the mapView will have no value allocated until I customize it and add its delegate. Hope this helps anyone else struggling with the same problem!